# iOs Printing my Current screen

Tags: iphone, ios

Currently I am working on a Paint Application for iPhones and iPads. I want to print the current screen display (Drawing) of the screen. Can any body help me in these case ?

Here is the code i have used so far ,

```
-(void)printImage { 
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"micky" ofType:@"png"];
    NSData *dataFromPath = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

    UIPrintInteractionController *pCon = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

    if(pCon && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData:dataFromPath]) {
        pCon.delegate = self;   
        UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
        printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
        printInfo.jobName = [path lastPathComponent];
        printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
        pCon.printInfo = printInfo;
        pCon.showsPageRange = YES;
        pCon.printingItem = dataFromPath;

        void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
            if (!completed && error) {
                NSLog(@"Unsuccessfull %@ error%u", error.domain, error.code);
            }
        };

        [pCon presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

    } 
}
```

Again , all what i want to know is i should be able to print the Current Window(Drawing, Screen) instead of the Image Micky.png (as in the code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code takes a screenshot of the current view and outputs an `UIImage` of it:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, YES, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *imageFromCurrentView = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Thanx thats work like charm . I want to Enhance this a bit more. If i want to get the screen shot of a particular view in my current screen, Then how can i do that ?

Comment: replace occurrences of `self.view` with whatever view you want to grab. Please mark this answer as accepted :)